# ActiveRecord relations when model has both one and many of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, belongs-to, has-one

My data resembles this:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :persons
  has_one :leader
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
end
```

Person only belongs to one Team, but of the many team members there is only 1 leader.

First question: should I use belongs_to instead of has_one in the Team model?

Second: Team is created with many Persons and the leader known initially. How should this be done?

Currently I am doing something like this in my controller:

```
  @team = Team.new

  for (each new person as p)

    new_person = @team.persons.build
    new_person.name = p.name

    if p.is_marked_as_leader
      @team.leader = new_person
    end
  end

  @team.save
```

This is a problem, when I list @team.persons, @team.leader has the first id, I assume because @team.save saves the leader association first. I need them to be in the order they are provided.

Thanks!

Comment: Please change the title of your question to a more meaningful one.

Comment: My bad, I was just editing it. Didn't mean to post like that.

Comment: vote to reopen before op creates a new one.

Comment: I added the problem I have with my creation in the controller. I neglected to mention it.

Comment: Can you please re-open the question? It's legitimate, I just had to edit. I posted it pre-maturely.

Answer (score 0):

I would vote for 'has_one' for the leader, because you the person can exist outside the team and her role as team lead.

It is the [aggregation vs composition](http://design-antony.blogspot.com/2007/07/aggregation-vs-composition.html) discussion.

Sometimes this is open to debate, but in this case I would say the team - leader relationship is clearly composition.

Comment: Oh, actually, the person cannot exist outside of the team and their role. The content in real use is more of a snapshot of a state of that Team in time, so the person represents the state of an external entity. Can I invert your answer to suggest that for the same reason it should in fact be belongs_to?

Comment: As I said : it is the old A vs C discussion ;-). Let me put it another way : if you delete the team, would you delete the person who is teamlead? This is a test to distinguish A from C.

Comment: Yeah, I would delete them. Thanks :)